# difference between a pointer and a pointer array

Tags: c++

I made a code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int *x,*y;
    x=new int[1];
    y=new int;
    cin>>y;   //Gives error probably because y is a pointer and not a variable
    cin>>*y                 //works fine
    cin>>x[0]>>x[1];
    cout<<x[0]<<x[1];
    cout<<*x[0];         //gives error
    cout<<y;
    cout<<*y;

    getch();

}
```

gives error.why?I remember i declared x as a pointer array and now i m doing the same i did with *y.Does it mean that a pointer array becomes a variable?plz help!

Comment: One error it should give is the `void main`.

Comment: `x` and `y` are both variables of type _pointer to int_. The reason for the first error is that istream has no overloaded extraction operator for reading a pointer (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), and the reason for the second error is that you are attempting to dereference something not of pointer type (`x[0]` has type `int`).

Comment: @warrenm  i thought i created array of pointers that are pointing to  int and not array of int. what can i do to create array of pointers?

Comment: @Smatik, I'm just saying it should. Any return type other than `int` is deemed undefined behaviour by the C++ standard.

Comment: @chris void main is not giving any error. Why should it give? i have not specified any return.

Comment: It is not the standard way of writing the Main function. I'm going to guess that you use visual studio? Also give 0[x] a shot. Might surprise you as to what you get as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually doing with that line of code is similar to:

```
cout<<**x;
```

Because using `x[0]` will dereference the `0th` element of `x`.

As you can see by your definition of `x`, `x` is just a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer, so dereferencing it twice will not work since you are trying to dereference a variable.

What the line:

```
x=new int[1];
```

is actually doing is just saying "assign an array of ints, size 1 to this pointer", which will just make `x` point to a block of memory big enough to store 1 int.

Answer (score 1):

x is a pointer to an int. You have allocated an array of ints, which is a single int long. Therefore x[0] is an int and *x is an int. However, *x[0] means you are saying that x[0] is a pointer which you are dereferencing. However, it isn't a pointer, it is an int. That is why there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the array:

```
x[0]
```

is equivalent to *(x+0);

As you know array is array is nothing but pointer in its root.

So any array that has x[a] or x[a][b] can be expanded as

```
*(x+a) or *(*(x+a)+b)
```

Based on this , i hope you found your answer.

Comment: An array is *not* a pointer, though it can be implicitly converted to one.